# What is a typical time to deploy an application to the cloud?

Tags: docker, deployment

We have a typical Dockerized Node/Express app that is deployed to about 100 machines on Digital Ocean. Currently, the entire deploy - not counting testing - takes about an hour.

I am used to deploys that take maybe 10-15 minutes, even for thousands of machines.

I am a bit confused about what is going on (their deploy system is rather bespoke) and have begun to gather data. The images are built in the cloud, so it's not something obvious like upload time from someone's laptop.

However, that's not my main problem. The main problem is that nobody in this company thinks that one hour is a problematic amount of time for this deploy. (It used to be five hours.)

Can you point me to data about what *is* a reasonable amount of time?

UPDATE: as many commenters surmised, originally it was not parallelized. This is the main reason why it *used* to take five hours. However, now it is parallelized (with a home-grown system running on top of Ansible, which ought to be parallelized already? I don't understand it). And it still takes an hour.

My intuition is not that we need to invest lots of engineering-hours optimizing anything, but that we just need to use more standard tools.

NOTE: Shaming my co-workers is offtopic. Many of the people here are junior or are just inexperienced, and I am far more senior.

Comment: I would bet you do it serially, not in parallel. 100 machines leaves not a lot of time one by one - and that is not needed. Start moving towards more parallel deployment.

Comment: Are you trying to convince your coworkers, or your management? You'll likely need different arguments for each.

Comment: @TomTom see above UPDATE

Comment: @MichaelHampton coworkers now, management later

Comment: Recent experience last patching weekend reminds me you really want to have local package caches (yum, apt, pip, npm, etc. as well as a regular http cache). Deployment can end up trying to pull packages (eg. using yum) many times from one vendors site, and that can easily invoke rate limiting).

Answer (score 2):

**According to me**, there is no 'typical time to deploy an app to the cloud' that fits everyone.

It depends on multiple items :

- application stack complexity
- automation levels
- team skills
- infrastructure components performance
- ...

You already moved from 5 hours to 1 hour, which is a great improvement.
Managers were fine with 5 hours, they are now happier with 1 hour (I suppose).

How often do you completely redeploy your application ?
What will be the cost to achieve a saving of 30 or 45 minutes ?
What do they will benefit from saving 30 or 45 minutes more ?
Can you present to your management the ROI of saving those 30 or 45 minutes ?

Some people just don't want to save those 30 minutes more if it means lots of mendays of engineering, increased complexity in automation, involving more and more skilled people to hire & train, and also increased times to troubleshoot issues.

Comment: It's a Node.js application that talks to Mongo. Could not be more standard.

Comment: You're asking a good question about ROI. In practice, because deploys are slow and complex, we don't deploy on a regular basis, and other teams are never sure when or if we deployed the feature they wanted. 

So we make our lives harder and slow down other teams. My ultimate goal is to instill the values of continuous delivery.  http://pushtrain.club/

Comment: "It's a Node.js application that talks to Mongo" - you run "npm install"? THAT can take ages, especially when not using a local cache. Also totally not needed - make that on a build server, unpack results on machines.

Answer (score 2):

A handful of minutes unless the deployment does significant database restructuring.

Your timeframe looks like it is a script running in a loop per machine. WHich makes no sense - if you have 100 machines, you should start paralellizing your deployment.

Comment: This is what I thought. Barring a database migration, such a deploy ought to take a few minutes at most.

Comment: Depending what you use as technology it may be as simple as a wrong setting (max 1 machine at a time instead of max x machines at a time).

Comment: The way I read the question, it appears they are using someone's homegrown custom scripts. He said: "their deploy system is rather bespoke".

Comment: Agree, but that may also mean custom scripts and a scheduler to control it - though more unlikely.

Comment: See update above - the scripts are parallelized, it's just parallelized with a homegrown system. They had trouble working with Ansible's parallelization so they wrote their own.